# How to use Enums in UITableView properly?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, enums

In my ViewController I've created an Enum:

```
enum ItemType: String {
    case Restaurant, Boutique, Resort
}
```

in `didSelect` I use:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToItemsList", sender: ItemType.Restaurant.hashValue)
```

later, in:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "goToItemsList" {
        let itemsListTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ItemsListTableViewController
        itemsListTableViewController.cellType = sender!
    }
}
```

So, how can I now check in my `ItemsListTableViewController`

```
if cellType == .Restaurant {
   // Do something
}
```

? I know, for this, I need do something like:

```
var a: ItemType
```

and just later to check that, but I cannot set the type of my `a` to `ItemType` in my ItemsListTableViewController.

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: ItemType(rawValue: sender! as String) == .Restaurent

Comment: @RJE but my second tableviewcontroller does not see ItemType

Comment: use `itemsListTableViewController.cellType = ItemType(rawValue: sender! as String)` assuming cellType is a 'ItemType' -- var cellType: ItemType. Ah.. u mean Item type is not visible in second VC. If you define enum globally other swift classes should see it.

Comment: Also, use `rawValue` instead of `hashValue` in `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do like this

in didSelectRow

you can use rawValue property. it returns The corresponding value of the "raw" type.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToItemsList", sender: ItemType.Restaurant.rawValue)
```

and in prepareForSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if segue.identifier == "goToItemsList" {

  let itemsListTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ItemsListTableViewController
  itemsListTableViewController.cellType = ItemType(rawValue: sender! as? String)
}
}
```

and in other view controller

```
var cellType :ItemType?
```

either you can directly check or can use switch

```
if let value = cellType {

switch(value) {

case .Boutique: // do something here
 break
case .Resort: // do something here
break
case .Restaurant: // do something here
break
}

}
```

Comment: I get `Cannot assign value of type 'MainViewController.ItemType?' to type 'String'` this error in `ItemType(rawValue: sender! as String)`

Comment: okay. just  make a cellType of  ItemType
var cellType :ItemType?

Comment: My problem was ecaxtly that. In my second VC - ItemType is not visible

Comment: just declare ItemType outside the class. i mean globally.
it will solve your problem.

Comment: You can access the enum within a second class as I've depicted above.

Comment: yes he can @armin. but that's not a good approach. if he wants to use it in multiple controller he should create it outside the class , so he can declare enum type in other controllers without having name of firstController.

Comment: I agree, but that was his initial question, and judging by his comments, he's still trying to use the same approach. I provided him with the way to do things the way he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the enums from your ViewController like:

```
ViewController.ItemType
```

Or, to match your example:

```
var a : ViewController.ItemType
```